# How come I cannot assign variables in Scala in the following manner?

Tags: scala

I have stripped down the method so it doesn't make logical sense but I am just trying to resolve the compile error

```
def getVWAP(date: Date, maxEvents: Int): Double = {

    var startDateTime = null;

    if (maxEvents > 0) {
        startDateTime = date; // error
    }

    0.0
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Scala has used [type inference](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/127) to deduce the type of the variable `startDateTime`, which you did not specify a type for.  So, Scala emits the following error:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : Date
 required: Null
           startDateTime = date; // error
```

This says, it thinks `startDateTime` should be of type Null, but you are giving it a `Date`.

The fix is to explicitly type `startDateTime` as follows:

```
var startDateTime : Date = /* some sort of default date */
```

If your `startDateTime` is truly optional, consider using Scala's [Option](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html) instead of using `null`.  This would make your function look like this:

```
def getVWAP(date: Date, maxEvents: Int): Double = {
    var startDateTime: Option[Date] = None;
    if (maxEvents > 0) {
        startDateTime = Some(date);
    }
    0.0
}
```

You can read more about [the philosophy of `Option`](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-scalas-and-haskells-types-will-save.html) versus `null` [here](http://james-iry.blogspot.com/2010/08/why-scalas-and-haskells-types-will-save.html). Overly summarized, `null` is about run-time checking, resulting in a `NullPointerException` if some variable is null, and `Option` is about compile-time checking, resulting in a compiler error indicating a potential non-value must be handled. Using `Option` says you'd rather know at compile time.

Comment: Wow we have pretty much the same posts. Darn you for winning the race ;)

Comment: I was just editing my response to include an example of how to use `Option`, which also looks remarkably like yours. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Because `startDateTime` is declared with type `Null`.  Can't assign a date to that.  Declare a type for `startDateTime` in your declaration.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably because they type of `startDateTime` is not inferred as a `Date`. Try replacing that line with

```
var startDateTime:Date = //(some initialized Date value)
```

One big difference between Scala and Java that you'll find is the avoidance of using `null`. If you really want a variable that might not be set, you should look into [Options](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Option.html)

In that case, you would define your startDateTime as

```
var startDateTime:Option[Date] = None
if(maxEvents > 0){
  startDateTime = Some(date)
}
```